# Play Audio Player when location speed decreases

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, cllocation

How to play audioplayer when location speed greater than 20,count time start for five second and when suddenly location
speed (speed decrease from 20 t0 0)equal to zero it play audio player.I try this but nothing happend plz help me.Here is my code

```
int i;

- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location{
    speedLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2fmph",[location speed]*2.236936284];

    if (location.speed >= 10)
    {
        [self performSelector:@selector(doThis) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];
        if (location.speed ==0) {
            [audioPlayer play];
        }
    }
}

-(void)doThis{
    if(i %5 == 0)     
    {
        [CLController.locMgr startUpdatingLocation];
    }
}
```

Comment: what increments "`i`"?

Answer (score 0):

Your condition check will not play audio. Make the changes as given,

```
int i;

- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location{
    speedLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2fmph",[location speed]*2.236936284];

    if (location.speed >= 10)
    {
        [self performSelector:@selector(doThis) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];

    }
    else if (location.speed ==0) {
        [audioPlayer play];
    }

}

-(void)doThis{
if(i %5 == 0)     
{
    [CLController.locMgr startUpdatingLocation];
}
}
```